# Couchbase admin tool falling over with filtered document list

Tags: couchbase, couchapp

I'm using the couchbase admin tool and one of the most useful features for me is the ability to go into the documents of a particular bucket and then using the document filter dialog I type a document prefix that I've reserved for a particular document type and then I immediately get a filtered list of just documents of this type. 
[image]

For instance, if I had a bucket called "sports" which had data for all sorts of sports, I might have set of records related to tennis, football, etc. and let's assume that the ID's of these documents were all prefixed with the particular sport in question. So in this case I'd simply put `football` into the **Document Filter** dialog and would expect to see just those documents whose ID's start with "football". This is happening as I type. This functionality works perfectly fine on my main development machine but on my laptop and in my production environment typing results in nothing as I type. I can press the "Lookup Id" button on any environment and as long as a proper ID has been specified it will load the document but the real-time filtering is for me critical to making the admin functionality useful to me.

It's worth mentioning that both my main dev machine and laptop are on OSX and production is Ubuntu. Also of note, my main development environment is still creeping around on version 2.0.1 because I'm afraid of losing this functionality but my laptop is running 2.5.1 and I think prod is the same.

Also, looking at the network panel in the debugger I do notice an important variation:

- Both laptop and main dev machines load the document viewer without any JS errors
- Independant of typing on into the filter dialog my main dev fires off REST calls periodically to: `http://couchserver:8091/pools/default?uuid=xxxxxx&waitChange=20000&etag=xxxxxx`
- As soon as I type into the filter dialog I see network requests that look like this: `http://couchserver:8091/couchBase/reference_data/_all_docs?startkey=%22football%22&endkey=%22football%EF%BF%BF%22&skip=0&include_docs=true&limit=21&_=1399627171015`
- My laptop, where the functionality doesn't work, does also seem to have the basic polling message listed above but when I type into the filter dialog no message is sent (and no JS error thrown either). Just silence. :(

Comment: Hi Ken, this isn't really an answer per se but really I'd recommend always interacting with your documents via the sdks.  I only ever use that feature for looking up a specific id that I already know, the problem may be frustrating for you but I'd reiterate again, use the sdk.

Comment: @scalability, I have no problem using the SDK but the use case is a very common "ad-hoc request" and therefore seems like its a very sensible functionality in the admin interface. Right? I mean now I need to create a command-line or GUI tool (leveraging the SDK) for myself to mimic the same thing? Why?

Comment: I imagine this functionality isn't intended for production use.

Comment: I mainly use it in development (where the admin is a useful tool too) but it this use case can be helpful in production too. Let's say you're troubleshooting a problem and you want to compare how many documents start with "xyz_" and compare that to a test environment to ensure consistency. This is just the first example that comes to mind, there must be many others.

Comment: Ok fair point on development, but in production with millions to billions of documents you'd be better off with using a view to emit how many documents are of a particular type.

Comment: Yes for transactional buckets where that many records exist then a View would make sense (not for adhoc so much as repeatable searches), however, if some of your buckets are geared for reference data the scale of these buckets is likely to be totally different and likely this filter feature is completely appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from IRC and other channels that this functionality has been removed because it was causing stability problems with large datasets. This is a bit worrisome to me and I still feel strongly that this functionality is highly desirable in an admin tool (at least in development environments although I would argue both prod and dev).

Anyway, while the UI still uses the "filter" terminology I think it's fair to say the filter terminology has been removed. I will now have to write my own admin interface. :(